# OpenSSL compiled version not matching the installed version?

Tags: linux, security, openssl, version, upgrade

I wanted to ask you something that it's happening probably since ever and I didn't notice until now.

Some days ago I upgraded openssl to the latest version (1.1.1k)  in a Debian server

I recently installed a software on the server to check vulnerabilities but it's still alerting about an old openssl version.

For some reason, when I run the "**openssl version**" command, it shows up this information:

**OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019)**

I wonder if I did something wrong when I compiled it. This are the instructions I'm using:

*./config --prefix=/usr/local/ssl --openssldir=/usr/local/ssl shared zlib-dynamic*

*make*

*make install*

Have you ever had a similar problem before? Do you know how to fix it?

Thanks.

[Edited]

I have installed a brand new server with Debian 10, minimal install (network). I have downloaded and compiled zlib and openssl. Once again, if I run  "/usr/local/ssl/bin/openssl version" I got the same results:
**OpenSSL 1.1.1k  25 Mar 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019)**

[Edit2 ]
I have installed a brand new virtual server with only Debian 10, minimal no packages installed by default. I have used only openssl 1.1.1k, downloaded and still the same problem:
(Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1d  10 Sep 2019) openssl 1.1.1k

Answer (score 0):

What is the output if you run:

```
openssl version
```

and

```
which openssl
```

?

Those commands together will tell you what version of openssl your operating system has in its path. I would think that the compilation of openssl either did not run succesfully or did not install openssl in the proper place.

You can see if there are other openssl binaries in your server by running:

```
find / -name openssl
```

as root. If there are, you can check their versions to see if any of them has the version you expect.

As an extra word of advice, i would recommend that you download a pre compiled package instead of compiling directly in the server (For production servers, this is in itself a security risk). Additionally, did the compilation and install completed successfully? These usually have lengthy outputs, and maybe an error was missed.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, thank you for answering. 
Openssl version gives what I wrote on the first message:
OpenSSL 1.1.1k 25 Mar 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1d 10 Sep 2019)
which command didn't show any information.
find listed all the /usr/local/ssl.. entries, plus the untar files.

I'm going to compile it once again. I didn't see any errors but I'll try to check it more in-depth.

Comment: Hello:
Re-reading your post, it looks to me that you might be having an issue with the tool that detects the vulernabilty. What is the specific message, and what tool are you using? If it is an external vulerability scanner, what port and ip is it detecting?
"which" command should return the path of the openssl binary the OS uses (whatever is in the path.

Comment: Hi Ricardo, thank you for taking the time to answer. The fact that running the openssl version command gives the contradictory message:  OpenSSL 1.1.1k 25 Mar 2021 (Library: OpenSSL 1.1.1d 10 Sep 2019) makes me think that it's something else.

Answer (score 0):

A good idea too :

> remove the old version the way it was installed :
> - wether it was by RPM :
> $ dnf remove openssl openssl-devel
> - wether it was by compilation :
> $ make uninstall

Check that the openssl command doesn't report any version :
$ openssl version

and then re-install yours.

That worked for me after failing with all that's above.